Issue regarding uploading/spawing multiple controller for two robot in sign_sim/gz_sim?
I have been trying to load the two controller for two robot, But failed for loading /robot1/controllermanager
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, ExecuteProcess, IncludeLaunchDescription, RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command, FindExecutable, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare


def generate_launch_description():
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default=True)
    
    # Robot 1 description
    robot1_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [FindPackageShare("robot_description"),
                 "urdf", "practice_multi_update.xacro"]
            ),
            " ",
            "namespace:=",
            "robot1",
        ]
    )
    robot1_description = {"robot_description": robot1_description_content}
    
    # Robot 2 description
    robot2_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [FindPackageShare("robot_description"),
                 "urdf", "practice_multi_update.xacro"]
            ),
            " ",
            "namespace:=",
            "robot2",
        ]
    )
    robot2_description = {"robot_description": robot2_description_content}
    
    # Robot 1 state publisher
    robot1_state_pub_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        namespace="robot1",
        output="both",
        parameters=[robot1_description],
    )
    
    # Robot 2 state publisher
    robot2_state_pub_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        namespace="robot2",
        output="both",
        parameters=[robot2_description],
    )
    
    # Robot 1 joint state publisher GUI
    robot1_joint_state_publisher_node_gui = Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        namespace="robot1"
    )
    
    # Robot 2 joint state publisher GUI
    robot2_joint_state_publisher_node_gui = Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        namespace="robot2"
    )
    
    # RViz node
    rviz_node = Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="log",
    )
    
    # Robot 1 load controllers
    robot1_load_joint_state_broadcaster = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
             'joint_state_broadcaster', '-c', "/robot1/controller_manager"],
        output='screen'
    )

    robot1_load_joint_trajectory_controller = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
             "joint_trajectory_controller", '-c', "/robot1/controller_manager"],
        output='screen'
    )
    
    # Robot 2 load controllers
    robot2_load_joint_state_broadcaster = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
             'joint_state_broadcaster', '-c', "/robot2/controller_manager"],
        output='screen'
    )

    robot2_load_joint_trajectory_controller = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
             "joint_trajectory_controller", '-c', "/robot2/controller_manager"],
        output='screen'
    )
    
    # Robot 1 controllers configuration
    robot1_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare("robot_description"),
            "config",
            "prac_controller_robot1.yaml",
        ]
    )
    
    # Robot 2 controllers configuration
    robot2_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare("robot_description"),
            "config",
            "prac_controller_robot2.yaml",
        ]
    )
    
    # Robot 1 control node
    robot1_control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        namespace="robot1",
        parameters=[robot1_description, robot1_controllers],
        output="both",
    )
    
    # Robot 2 control node
    robot2_control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        namespace="robot2",
        parameters=[robot2_description, robot2_controllers],
        output="both",
    )
    
    # Robot 1 spawn entity
    robot1_ignition_spawn_entity = Node(
        package='ros_gz_sim',
        executable='create',
        output='screen',
        namespace="robot1",
        arguments=['-string', robot1_description_content,
                   '-name', "robot1",
                   '-allow_renaming', 'true',
                   '-x', "0.0",
                   '-y', "0.0",
                   '-z', "0.0",
                   ],
    )
    
    # Robot 2 spawn entity
    robot2_ignition_spawn_entity = Node(
        package='ros_gz_sim',
        executable='create',
        output='screen',
        namespace="robot2",
        arguments=['-string', robot2_description_content,
                   '-name', "robot2",
                   '-allow_renaming', 'true',
                   '-x', "5.0",
                   '-y', "0.0",
                   '-z', "0.0",
                   ],
    )
    gazebo_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ros_ign_gazebo'),
                         'launch', 'ign_gazebo.launch.py')
        ),
        launch_arguments={'gz_args': ' -r -v 4 empty.sdf'}.items()
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument('use_sim_time', default_value='true', description='Use simulation time if true'),
        gazebo_launch,
        robot1_state_pub_node,
        robot2_state_pub_node,
        # robot1_joint_state_publisher_node_gui,
        # robot2_joint_state_publisher_node_gui,
        rviz_node,
        robot1_control_node,
        robot2_control_node,
        robot1_ignition_spawn_entity,
        robot2_ignition_spawn_entity,
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=robot1_control_node,
                on_exit=[robot1_load_joint_state_broadcaster],
            )
        ),
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=robot1_load_joint_state_broadcaster,
                on_exit=[robot1_load_joint_trajectory_controller],
            )
        ),
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=robot2_control_node,
                on_exit=[robot2_load_joint_state_broadcaster],
            )
        ),
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=robot2_load_joint_state_broadcaster,
                on_exit=[robot2_load_joint_trajectory_controller],
            )
        ),
    ])

I have the yaml file for robot1
/robot1/controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100 # Hz


    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster


    joint_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController


/robot1/joint_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - robot1_joint_1

    write_op_modes:
      - robot1_joint_1
    
    interface_name: position

    command_interfaces:
      - position
    
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity

    state_publish_rate: 50.0 # Defaults to 50
    action_monitor_rate: 20.0 # Defaults to 20

    allow_partial_joints_goal: false # Defaults to false
    hardware_state_has_offset: true
    deduce_states_from_derivatives: true
    
    constraints:
      stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.01 # Defaults to 0.01
      goal_time: 0.0 # Defaults to 0.0 (start immediately)

I have the yaml file for robot2
/robot2/controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100 # Hz


    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster


    joint_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController


/robot2/joint_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - robot2_joint_1

    write_op_modes:
      - robot2_joint_1
    
    interface_name: position

    command_interfaces:
      - position
    
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity

    state_publish_rate: 50.0 # Defaults to 50
    action_monitor_rate: 20.0 # Defaults to 20

    allow_partial_joints_goal: false # Defaults to false
    hardware_state_has_offset: true
    deduce_states_from_derivatives: true
    
    constraints:
      stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.01 # Defaults to 0.01
      goal_time: 0.0 # Defaults to 0.0 (start immediately)

and xacro file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="robot_name">
    <xacro:arg name="namespace" default="RB" />
    <xacro:property name="prefix" value="$(arg namespace)_" />


    <link name="${prefix}base_footprint">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="1.0 1.0 0.1" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="LightGrey">
                <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="1.0 1.0 0.1" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.0" />
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0" />
        </inertial>
    </link>
    <joint name="${prefix}base_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="${prefix}base_footprint" />
        <child link="${prefix}base_link" />
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.05" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="${prefix}base_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.5" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 1.0" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="LightGrey">
                <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.5" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 1.0" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="1.0" />
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.5" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
            <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0.0" izz="0.01" />
        </inertial>
    </link>
    <joint name="${prefix}joint_1" type="revolute">
        <parent link="${prefix}base_link" />
        <child link="${prefix}child_link" />
        <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
        <limit lower="-3.14159" upper="3.14159" velocity="50.0" effort="1000.0" />
        <origin xyz="0.1 0 0.9" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>
    <link name="${prefix}child_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.3" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 0.8" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="LightGrey">
                <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.3" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 0.6" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="1.0" />
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.3" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
            <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0.0" izz="0.01" />
        </inertial>
    </link>
    <ros2_control name="IgnitionSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>ign_ros2_control/IgnitionSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>

        <joint name="${prefix}joint_1">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">-3</param>
                <param name="max">3</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position" />
            <state_interface name="velocity" />
            <state_interface name="effort" />
        </joint>

    </ros2_control>
    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="ign_ros2_control-system"
            name="ign_ros2_control::IgnitionROS2ControlPlugin">
            <!-- <robot_param>/$(arg namespace)/robot_description</robot_param> -->
            <!-- <robot_param_node>/$(arg namespace)/robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node> -->
            <controller_manager_prefix_node_name>$(arg namespace)</controller_manager_prefix_node_name>
            <ros>
                <namespace>$(arg namespace)</namespace>
                <remapping>/tf:=/$(arg namespace)/tf</remapping>
            </ros>
            <parameters>$(find robot_description)/config/prac_controller_$(arg namespace).yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
</robot>

Error is
ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107211.894796495] [GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin]: robot_param_node is robot_state_publisher
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107211.894832735] [GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin]: robot_param_node is robot_description
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.257423321] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]: connected to service!! /robot2/robot_state_publisher asking for robot_description
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.258672981] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]: Received URDF from param server
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263114767] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]: The position_proportional_gain has been set to: 0.1
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263168953] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]: Loading joint: robot2_joint_1
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263180525] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]:    State:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263189227] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]:             position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263197684] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]:             velocity
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263205057] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]:             effort
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263211895] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]:    Command:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263218691] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]:             position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263269145] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'IgnitionSystem' 
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1720107212.263286180] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]: On init...
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263331854] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'IgnitionSystem'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263366203] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'IgnitionSystem' 
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263371511] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]: System Successfully configured!
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263382738] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'IgnitionSystem'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263388804] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'IgnitionSystem' 
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263394719] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'IgnitionSystem'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.263401876] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]: Loading controller_manager
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.343513936] [GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin]: robot_param_node is robot_state_publisher
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.343533347] [GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin]: robot_param_node is robot_description
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.350886256] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]: connected to service!! /robot1/robot_state_publisher asking for robot_description
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.351165710] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]: Received URDF from param server
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353692996] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]: The position_proportional_gain has been set to: 0.1
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353748568] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]: Loading joint: robot1_joint_1
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353758832] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]:    State:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353766922] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]:             position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353775281] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]:             velocity
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353782920] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]:             effort
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353790410] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]:    Command:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353797753] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]:             position
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353828786] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'IgnitionSystem' 
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1720107212.353835874] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]: On init...
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353850800] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'IgnitionSystem'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353864841] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'IgnitionSystem' 
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353870226] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]: System Successfully configured!
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353880289] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'IgnitionSystem'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353886728] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'IgnitionSystem' 
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353892961] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'IgnitionSystem'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.353898106] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]: Loading controller_manager
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1720107212.365260629] [robot1.controller_manager]: 'update_rate' parameter not set, using default value.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1720107212.371377999] [robot1.gz_ros2_control]: controller manager doesn't have an update_rate parameter
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Wrn] [Component.hh:144] Trying to serialize component with data type [N3sdf3v125WorldE], which doesn't have `operator<<`. Component will not be serialized.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Wrn] [Component.hh:189] Trying to deserialize component with data type [N3sdf3v125WorldE], which doesn't have `operator>>`. Component will not be deserialized.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1720107212.387373019] [robot2.gz_ros2_control]:  Desired controller update period (0.01 s) is slower than the gazebo simulation period (0.001 s).
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.497306956] [robot2.controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1720107212.499999677] [robot1.controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'joint_state_broadcaster'.
[ros2-9] Error loading controller, check controller_manager logs
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.515354525] [robot2.controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107212.515618375] [robot2.joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[ros2-10] Successfully loaded controller joint_state_broadcaster into state active
[ERROR] [ros2-9]: process has died [pid 19933, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active joint_state_broadcaster -c /robot1/controller_manager'].
[INFO] [ros2-11]: process started with pid [20199]
[INFO] [ros2-10]: process has finished cleanly [pid 19935]
[INFO] [ros2-12]: process started with pid [20201]
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1720107213.626074437] [robot1.controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'joint_trajectory_controller'.
[ros2-11] Error loading controller, check controller_manager logs
[ERROR] [ros2-11]: process has died [pid 20199, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active joint_trajectory_controller -c /robot1/controller_manager'].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107215.936363208] [robot2.controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_trajectory_controller'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1720107215.956249412] [robot2.joint_trajectory_controller]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107215.968568208] [robot2.controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_trajectory_controller'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107215.968697321] [robot2.joint_trajectory_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107215.968723966] [robot2.joint_trajectory_controller]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position velocity].
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107215.968740359] [robot2.joint_trajectory_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107215.969850299] [robot2.joint_trajectory_controller]: Controller state will be published at 50.00 Hz.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1720107215.971066267] [robot2.joint_trajectory_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[ros2-12] Successfully loaded controller joint_trajectory_controller into state active
[INFO] [ros2-12]: process has finished cleanly [pid 20201]


You cannot use ros2_control_node along gazebo/ign/gz_ros2_control, see the ign_ros2_control demos how to spawn your robots in gazebo.
We don't have a multi-robot demo yet, but you should be able to load two gz_ros2_control plugins within their own namespace.
I'm not sure now, maybe the namespaces will be applied twice if you namespace them also in the yaml file? Have a look with rqt_reconfigure or similar, which parameters are set for the two controller managers?
When you get it working, we'd appreciate if you submit a PR with a multi-robot example to gz_ros2_control.
